# CMFormatDescription to CMVideoFormatDescription

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to get the resolution of the camera of a device using swift.

I'm using CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions which requires a CMVideoFormatDescription, but AVCaptureDevice.formatDescription returns a CMFormatDescription. I've tried a multitude of ways to cast CMFormatDescription to CMVideoFormatDescription and can't seem to get it working.

Below is a sample of the code that I'm using:

```
for format in device.formats as [AVCaptureDeviceFormat] {
  let videoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format.formatDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible in Swift at the moment. One solution then would be to write a helper function in objective-c, such as:

```
CMVideoDimensions CMFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription)
{
    if (CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(formatDescription) == kCMMediaType_Video)
        return CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription);
    else
        return (CMVideoDimensions) {
            .width = 0,
            .height = 0
        };
}
```

Include the header with the function prototype in the Swift bridging header so that it will be accessible as a global function from your Swift code.

Comment: That is a solution, it is disappointing however that swift currently doesn't map very well to the low level cocoa APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the resolution using the swift method below:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice

let formatDesc = captureDevice.activeFormat.formatDescription
let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDesc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in pure Swift, really only usable for logging purposes and such. Paste the following function in your class or somewhere else:

```
func widthAndHeightFromTrack(track: AVAssetTrack) -> CGSize {
    let str = track.formatDescriptions.description

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]{2,4} x [0-9]{2,4}", options: [])
    if let result = regex.firstMatchInString(str, options: [], range:  NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)) {
        let dimensionString = (str as NSString).substringWithRange(result.range)
        let dimensionArray = dimensionString.componentsSeparatedByString(" x ")
        let width = Int(dimensionArray[0])
        let height = Int(dimensionArray[1])
        return CGSize(width: width!, height: height!)
    }

    return CGSizeZero
}
```

Example usage:

```
let allTracks: AVAsset = someAVAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
let videoTrack = allTracks[0]
let videoTrackDimensions = widthAndHeightFromTrack(videoTrack)
// You now have a CGSize, print it
print("Dimensions: \(videoTrackDimensions)")
```

Of course, the above solution will completely break whenever Apple changes something in the string representation of the CMFormatDescription. But it's useful for logging the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, question is too old, but the Swift issue is still not fixed.

```
public extension AVURLAsset {

    var audioFormatDescription: CMAudioFormatDescription? {

        if  let track = self.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first,
            let untypedDescription = track.formatDescriptions.first {

            // hacks, warnings, disablings of swiftlint below are wrork-around of
            //      Swift bug: it fails converting 'Any as CMFormatDescription'
            let forceTyped: CMFormatDescription?
//swiftlint:disable force_cast
                                                    = untypedDescription as! CMAudioFormatDescription
//swiftlint:enable force_cast
            if  let description = forceTyped {
                return description
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```